# Anticyclotomic extensions via ideles

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $ K $ be an imaginary quadratic field with ring of integers $ \mathcal{O} $. Let $ \mathcal{O}_{n} = \mathbb{Z} + n \mathcal{O} $ be the order of conductor $ n $. There is an associated extension $ K_{n} $ such that $$  \mathrm{Gal}(K_{n}/K) \cong  \mathrm{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_{n}) $$
which is referred to as  *ring class field of conductor* $ n $ in literature. Adelically, this may be described as the extension associated to the compact open subgroup $ \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{n} = \mathcal{O}_{n} \otimes \widehat{\mathbb{Z}} $ (profinite completion of $ \mathcal{O}_{n}$) of $   \mathbb{A}_{K,f} ^{\times} $, so that $$ \mathbb{A}_{K}^{\times}/K^{\times}\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{n}C_{E} \cong \mathbb{A}_{K,f}/K^{\times} \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{n}  \cong  \mathrm{Gal}(K_{n}/K) $$
where $ \mathbb{A}_{K,f} $ denotes the finite adeles of $ K$, $ C_{E} \cong \mathbb{C} $ is the connected component the idele class group. Given $ n $, $ m \geq 1 $, $ \mathcal{O}_{nm} \subset \mathcal{O}_{n}, \mathcal{O}_{m} $, whence $ K_{n}, K_{m} \subset K_{nm} $. The filtered direct limit/compositum $$  K_{\infty} = \bigcup_{n} K_{n} $$
is referred to as the *anticyclotomic abelian extension of* $K$.

Let $ T = \mathrm{Res}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{G}_{m}$, and $ U_{1} $ be norm $ 1 $ elements in $ T $ i.e. for $ \mathbb{Q}$-algebra $ R $, let $$ U_{1} (R) =   \left \{ x \in  ( R   \otimes K ) ^ {\times} | x \sigma(x) = 1 \right \}  $$
where $ \sigma  \in  \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) $ is the non-trivial element. There is a $ \mathbb{Q}  $-map $$ \phi :  T \to U_{1} \quad \quad   x  \mapsto \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$ and hence a continuous map $$  \phi : \mathrm{Gal}(K^{\mathrm{ab}}/K)  \xrightarrow{\cong} \mathbb{A}_{K,f}^{\times} / E^ {\times}  \to  U_{1} (  \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q},f})/U_{1}(\mathbb{Q}) .$$
Let $ H = \mathrm{ker} \phi $.

**Question:** Is $ \phi $ surjective? What is the fixed field of $ H $? Is it the anticyclotomic extension $ K_{\infty} $? If all of these are affirmative, are there compact open subgroups $  C_{n} \subset U_{1} (\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q},f}) $, such that $ \mathrm{Gal}(K_{n}/K)  \cong    U_{1} ( \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q},f})   / U_{1}(\mathbb{Q}) C_{n} $?

Comment: Surjectivity follows by Hilbert 90

Comment: The article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.00998.pdf, seems to answer all my questions. I'll write the answer to my post for the benefit of anyone looking for similar facts.